# Changing header color in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to set the header color of Chrome in an html page, but it is not working.
I remember it working before, now it doesn't.

Here is the code (placed in the "head" tag):

`<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff0000" />`

I can't find a solution, everyone is using this code but it is not working for me.
Testing on Chrome V.41.0.2272 on Lollipop (5.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android)

`<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff0000" />`

is correct but remember that the header has colors only if the option `Merge tabs and apps` in Chrome is on.

Comment: You are right! I tryed it before posting but it wasn't working, then found out it was a cache problem. Thank you!